Binding Parameters with Rails ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query in mysql
I am attempting to utilize binding parameters in Rails using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query for a mysql database, but I'm doing something wrong.
Here is the code:
query = "Select * from accounts where name = ? AND description = ?"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query,name = "SQL",[ [nil, "Some account"], [nil, "Some Desc"] ])

When run it gives this error:

SQL (68.7ms)  Select * from accounts where name = ? AND description = ?


ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND description = ?' at line 1

Here is the documentation for exec_query.
I understand that there are alternatives:

Account.where("name=? AND description=?", "Some account", "Some Desc")
Account.where(name: "Some account", description: "Some Desc")

However, I'm trying to figure out how to using binding parameters within the context of exec_query.
For context, in the test environment I am using mysql2 (0.5.6) and mysql 8.0.

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query,name = "SQL",[ "Some account", "Some Desc" ])

@dbugger same error for me: "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND description = ?' at line 1"

Add the versions of MySQL engine and the mysql gem you are using to the question

Did you see this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20498

@dbugger good point, I added those details in the original question.

@spickermann interesting, no I did not see that issue.

If prepared_statements is false, which it is by default for the mysql adapter (Source) then the binds are ignored entirely.

Probably your bindings are done incorrectly. Try something like this:
query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = $1 AND description = $2"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query, "SQL", [[nil, "Some account"], [nil, "Some Desc"]])

Also, you can consider the sanitize_sql_array method as an alternative:
query = ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql_array(
  [
    'SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = :name AND description = :description',
    { name: 'Some account', description: 'Some Desc' }
  ]
)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query, 'SQL')


The binding at the top does not work for me. However, your alternative solution with sanitize_sql_array did work for me!

@Neil, please mark my message as an accepted answer if it helped you so others can find it easier. Thank you!
